# Error al usar limitTo como filtro en ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

Tengo un problema y es que quiero limitar la cantidad de letras que representa una propiedad de un objeto usando `limitTo`, me sale un error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe
>   'limitTo' could not be found ("click)="openCart()">
>
> {{ [ERROR ->]producto.description | limitTo: 50 }}

**Html**

```
<p class=" description">{{ producto.description | limitTo: 50 }}</p>
```

**js**

```
productos.description ="Product Description este 
      es mi texto describiendo las caracteristicas completas del 
      articulo, tales como: peso, tamaño, color, etc.";
```

Ver documentacion -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: Buenas, esto es angular 2? en caso de ser así, me parece que ya no existe ese pipe en esta versión.

Comment: contesta eso en la pregunta mas esta respuesta: miPipes.ts: import { 
   Pipe, 
   PipeTransform 
} from '@angular/core';  

@Pipe({ 
   name: 'miLimitTo' 
}) 

export class LimitTo implements PipeTransform { 
   transform(value: string, limite: string, desde: string): string { 
      let hasta = parseFloat(limite); 
      let inicio;
      let suspencivos="";
      if (parseFloat(desde)>0) {
       inicio = parseFloat(desde); 
       // code...
      }
      else{
       inicio = 0; 
      }
      if(value.length > hasta){

Comment: suspencivos = "... ";
      }
      return  value.substring(inicio, hasta)+suspencivos;
   } 
} 

app.module.ts: 

import { LimitTo } from '../pipes/miPipes'

declarations: [
    LimitTo
  ],
entryComponents: [
    LimitTo
  ]
en el Html: 
{{ expresión  | miLimitTo: cantidad }} o {{ expresión  | miLimitTo: cantidad : posicionInicio }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hago esta respuesta basada en tu comentario:

En angular 2, el filtro Pipe ya no existe, por lo cual, se necesita una custom Pipe (espero no te moleste, le hice unos cambios a tu código):

miPipes.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'; 
@Pipe({ name: 'miLimitTo' }) 

export class LimitToPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, limite: number, desde: number = 0): string { 
      return (value.length > limite)? value.substring(desde, limite) + '...': value.substring(desde, limite); 
  } 
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
...
import { LimitToPipe } from '../pipes/miPipes'
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, LimitToPipe ],
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [LimitToPipe]
})
```

Html:

```
<h2>{{name | miLimitTo:100:10}}</h2>
<h2>{{name | miLimitTo:100}}</h2>
```

Ejemplo funcional en Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/cinehfjc3f5opvjNK8zC?p=preview

Muchas gracias @DanielEnriqueRodriguezCaste